# Mutually exclude property in LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

I have a list on which there is a "Active" property that I would like to set to 1 only to an item and to 0 to all other items.

Which is the smartest way to do it in Linq? I know I could set to 0 to all items then 1 only to current, but I was asking if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Is there some predicate you'd use to decide which item gets 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a pair to Daniel's response, if you *must* use linq, that's just a perversion. At least just use it to find the item and then act on it.

```
var item = list.FirstOrDefault**(i => i == desired);

if (item != null)
{
    item.Active = true;
}
```

** Possible change to `First`, `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` depending on the nature of the list.

Comment: Beware: this doesn't set all others to false! If you are running this code twice with different values for `desired` you will end up with two active items.

Comment: @Daniel You're right! Really shouldn't mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that LINQ is particularly useful here... how about:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    item.Active = (item == desiredActiveItem ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jon, but if you want to use LINQ anyway, you could do something like this:

```
list = list.Select(i => { i.Active = (i == desiredActiveItem ? 1 : 0); 
                          return i; }).ToList();
```

This shows that it really is a good idea to not use LINQ here.